# UIview doesn't work property with viewdidappear

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a tableview project which has a view, everything that I do in this view is controlled by "viewdidappear" method.

I added a new UIview which has "lines.h" and "lines.m" files.

I use this view to draw some lines and works god.

This extra view is located in to a scroll view because is to long to display in to iPhones screen.

The problem is that viewdidappear doesn't reload the uiview data, it only works with viewdidload.

I have to close the application and reopen it to get my data reload.

Sorry for my bad English